# Replacing NA values within sequences for a state code

Tags: r, traminer

The dataset I work with is an already made long-shape one. It includes the working states of young adults, being the alphabet either part- or full- time contract. All `NA` values are to be considered as another state: unemployed. 
Checking [TramineR user's guide](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/1.4/TraMineR-1.4-Users-Guide.pdf) and `seqdef()` help seems like this could be possible to do directly when creating the STS object by `seqdef()`, as it is explained briefly in the [supporting documents](http://traminer.unige.ch/doc/seqdef.html):

> `left`:
>   the behavior for missing values appearing before the first (leftmost)
>   valid state in each sequence. See Gabadinho et al. (2010) for more
>   details on the options for handling missing values when defining
>   sequence objects. By default, left missing values are treated as
>   'real' missing values and converted to the internal missing value code
>   defined by the nr option. Other options are "DEL" to delete the
>   positions containing missing values **or a state code (belonging to the
>   alphabet or not) to replace the missing values**.

I have unsuccessfully tried replacing `*` and `%` values by a new state code, which is anyways treated as missing in practical terms (for instance, when plotting sequences). After examining `left`, `right` and `gaps` arguments it seems not to be the key either.

Could somebody give a hint how to specify the state code so `NA` values are actually treated as a state included in the alphabet? Thanks a lot beforehand!

Comment: To start, could you provide a reproducible example of your problem, providing sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where left, gaps and right NAs  are replaced by a new state `ne` (not in education).  Note how we add the element `ne` to the alphabet.

```
lab <- seqstatl(eduSTS.age)
long.lab <- c(lab, "not in education")
alphabet <- c(lab, "ne")
short.lab <- c("AP", "CS", "EV", "MA", "HS", "OT", "TV", "HV", "ne")
edu.seq <- seqdef(eduSTS.age, informat = "STS", alphabet = long.lab,
       states = short.lab, label = long.lab, missing = NA, left = "ne",
       gaps = "ne", right = "ne")
```

Actually, as you can see in the example above, the string passed as `left`, `gaps`, or `right` argument should be one of the `states` (short labels). If this is not an existing state, you have to add it to the `states`, but you also need to add a corresponding element to the `alphabet` and, if you use it, to the long `label`.

Hope this helps.